# Change a group of values in a list of association

Tags: filtering, associations

Noob here.

I want to change the value of all the keys "e", that meet my filter criteria ("c" and "d" are above or equal 20).

```
myAsc = {
   <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 1, "c" -> 10, "d" -> 10, "e" -> 0|>,
   <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 0|>,
   <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 0|>,
   <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 4, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 0|>,
   <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 10, "d" -> 10, "e" -> 0|>
   };
```

With Cases, I filter the Associations I want:

```
Cases[myAsc, x_ /; x["c"] >= 20 && x["d"] >= 20]


{<|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 0|>,
 <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 0|>,
 <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 4, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 0|>}
```

And so far I understand that I can use ReplacePart to change a value of "e" inside my list of Association.

```
ReplacePart[myAsc, {2, "e"} -> 1]
{<|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 1, "c" -> 10, "d" -> 10, "e" -> 0|>, 
 <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 1|>, 
 <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 0|>,
 <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 4, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 0|>,
 <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 10, "d" -> 10, "e" -> 0|>}
```

How can I combine this and change all values of "e" that met the filter criteria at once.

My desired output would be:

```
{<|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 1, "c" -> 10, "d" -> 10, "e" -> 0|>, 
 <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 1|>, 
 <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 1|>,
 <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 4, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 1|>,
 <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 10, "d" -> 10, "e" -> 0|>}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pos = Position[myAsc, x_ /; x["c"] >= 20 && x["d"] >= 20]
```

> `{{2}, {3}, {4}}`

```
ReplacePart[myAsc, ({First@#, "e"} -> 1) & /@ pos]
```

> ```
> {
>   <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 1, "c" -> 10, "d" -> 10, "e" -> 0|>
> , <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 1|
> , <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 1|
> , <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 4, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 1|>
> , <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 10, "d" -> 10, "e" -> 0|>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
ReplaceAll[x_ /; x["c"] >= 20 && x["d"] >= 20 :> ReplacePart[x, "e" -> 1]] @ myAsc
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
myAsc // Map[<|#,"e"-> Boole[#["c"] >= 20 && #["d"] >= 20]|>&]
```

```
{Association["a" -> 0, "b" -> 1, "c" -> 10, "d" -> 10, "e" -> 0], 
Association["a" -> 0, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 1], 
Association["a" -> 0, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 1], 
Association["a" -> 0, "b" -> 4, "c" -> 20, "d" -> 20, "e" -> 1], 
Association["a" -> 0, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 10, "d" -> 10, "e" -> 0]}
```